# Visual Studio devops Angular build fail

Tags: angular, npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am getting the following error when building on Visual Studio devops. The angular app builds successfully without any errors or warning on my local machine. But once I push my code to devops it fails.

```
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1' 

ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.
```

I am not sure why this is happening as this module is in my codebase

Full error log is in azure

```
##[section]Starting: ng build
==============================================================================
Task         : Command Line
Description  : Run a command line script using cmd.exe on Windows and bash on macOS and Linux.
Version      : 2.148.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613735)
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents:
ng build --prod
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
##[command]"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\6fc36bd3-465a-4f53-b285-bf7394f9804d.cmd""
Your global Angular CLI version (7.2.1) is greater than your local
version (6.2.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".

Date: 2019-04-05T12:50:09.381Z
Hash: dc9270fae725f3369d30
Time: 20486ms
chunk {0} runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js (runtime) 1.44 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.9868d9b237c3a48c54da.js (main) 128 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.85f47f0bf59079cbc23a.js (polyfills) 130 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} styles.3e8caf971803565fc40f.css (styles) 313 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.
src/app/services/tokenInterceptor.service.ts(11,10): error TS2305: Module '"D:/a/1/s/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.

##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
##[section]Finishing: ng build
```

Package.json
[image]

Comment: what angular version are you using?

Comment: version 6 of angular. I have added full log of azure build

Comment: and you definitely have rxjs and rxjs-compat installed?

Comment: yes 100%. checked again now

Comment: Could you share the screenshot of dependencies of the package.json file?

Comment: yes, added in question

Comment: `rxjs-compat` is _not_ in your package.json file...

Comment: is it not supposed to be added automatically after installing it?

Comment: That depends on the location where you install it, and the command line options you're using.

Comment: ok thanks. let me add it in and see what happens

Comment: You should remove rxjs-compat and refactor yout project to rxjs 6

Comment: Please install `rxjs-compat` by using `npm i rxjs-compat` command. It will work.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot guys. specifically adding the reference in package.json.    "rxjs-compat": "~6.3.3",

Comment: Great, please upvote the comment. Thanks

Comment: @skydev Great to hear this. Could you please expand your solution with more details in the answer then mark it, which will also help others in the community.

Comment: To sum up what happened is that I did install the package and it showed in my node_modules folder within my project however because it was not registered in my package.json meant that when Azure tried to build the project it was not installing the required module. This would have caused problems for anyone trying to run my project on another machine.